# Python: How to select a collection in the Outliner?

Tags: python, collections, outliner

I would like to set an active collection via python and have it selected in the Outliner.

Example: There are two collections A and B.

step 1: Manually select collection A in the Outliner.

step 2: Run

`bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children["B"]`

step 3: Observe that collection A is still selected in the Outliner, but I would like to have collection B to be selected.